# Product form of Mobius Inversion formula: $g(n)=\prod_{d|n}f(d)^{a(n/d)}\iff f(n)=\prod_{d|n} g(d)^{b(n/d)}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

> *Product form of the Möbius inversion formula*: If $f(n)>0$ for all $n$ and if $a(n)$ is real, $a(1)\neq 0$, prove that
> $$g(n)=\prod_{d|n}f(d)^{a(n/d)}\iff f(n)=\prod_{d|n} g(d)^{b(n/d)}$$
> where $b=a^{-1}$ is the Dirichlet inverse of $a$.

So, of course, we have
\begin{align*}
&b(1)=\frac 1{a(1)}\\
&b(n)=\frac {-1}{a(1)}\sum_{d|n}a\left(\frac nd\right)b(d)
\end{align*}

I tried taking logarithms which gave
$$\log g(n)=\sum_{d|n}a(n/d)\log f(d)$$
from which I can't go any further.

On googling *Product form of the Möbius inversion formula*, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Multiplicative_notation) gives an alternate statement
$$f(n) = \prod_{d|n}g(d)\iff g(n) = \prod_{d|n} f(d)^{\mu(n/d)}?$$
which can be pretty easily proved by taking logarithms.

But, how does this relate with the original question? Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: This should indeed follow from using the ordinary (sum) version of Möbius inversion (or its generalization to all Dirichlet inverses) applied to $F(n)=\log f(n)$ and $G(n)=\log g(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia's form is a specific case. Defining the unit function $u(n) = 1$, and defining the product Dirichlet multiplication by

$$\newcommand{\p}{\;\square\;}
(f \p g)(n) := \prod_{d \mid n} f(d)^{g(n/d)}$$

then Wikipedia is claiming that $f = g \p u \iff g = f \p u^{-1}$, where $u^{-1}$ is taken to the ***usual*** Dirichlet inverse. One can prove that $\mu \equiv u^{-1}$.

The statement you wish to prove is the more general

$$f = g \p a \iff g = f \p a^{-1}$$

---

So, taking logs as you have done, we get to

$$f = g \p a \implies \log(f) = \log(g) \ast a$$

for $\ast$ the usual Dirichlet multiplication. $a$ is invertible as $a(1) \ne 0$, so we can multiply by its inverse on both sides and get

$$\log(f) \ast a^{-1} = \log(g)$$

We then convert back to something more expressive:

$$\sum_{d \mid n} \log(f(d)) a(n/d) = \sum_{d \mid n} \log \left( f(d)^{a(n/d)} \right) = \log(g)$$

Now we exponentiate and the result follows.

Comment: Got it. Thanks (+1) It seems I missed a triviality.